# How exactly does a breaker finder work?

Tags: detection, circuit-breaker

I've used a [breaker finder](https://www.fluke.com/en-us/product/electrical-testing/basic-testers/fluke-t-plus-pro-1ac-kit) for a while now, and I'm curious as to how it actually works. The only explanations I can find online are layman explanations (e.g. it sends a signal up from the outlet to the breaker box). I can't possibly imagine that this might be the case... Can anyone provide any insight?

Comment: Probably just works like an antenna, or capacitive sensor. I assume the breaker needs to be open/not conducting.

Comment: Think RF paths via hot and logical codes for 5 faults with 3 LED indicators  with sender in outlet https://www.reedinstruments.com/pdfs/cache/www.reedinstruments.com/r5500/datasheet/r5500-datasheet.pdf

Comment: During my construction days, I would plug in a boom-box and flip breakers quickly til da moosic stopped.

Comment: I am not an expert,  but I think the transmitter just sends an AM signal at a MHz or so, and the receiver is a diode detector, amplifier, and speaker.  Both devices are connected to the line through small value capacitors.

Comment: @JohnCanon Keep this man away from hospitals under operation :P

Comment: @JohnCanon -- That works. I heard a story about an electrician in a large department store who explained that there were often many different places that the "right" breaker could be, and he couldn't spend all day looking for it, or randomly trying breakers in the store.  He wired up a light switch to a plug, and would simply plug it in and flip the switch, which would "find" the right breaker and turn it off immediately. Then he would leave it in just in case somebody else wondered why the breaker was off and turn it back on again, protecting him while he worked. I thought it was genius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you show in your link is a voltmeter and an AC field probe.

The AC field probe blade tip is basically an antenna. It feeds a high-gain amplifier to detect the AC electric field and in response make a ‘chirp’ and blink an LED. You stick this thing in your outlet and listen as you try each breaker to figure out which one controls the outlet.

The voltmeter is its own deal, and has nothing to do with the field probe.

On the other hand, there are *circuit tracers*. These work differently: they send a signal back up a wire, which you sniff out at the panel with a detector.